# TCP Server receiving from client doesn't work sometimes

Tags: python, sockets, networking, protocols

I'm working on a server written in Python for my own protocol, but I'm having an issue.
The client connects to the server, and `sendall()`'s three pieces of data: a packet identification byte, a string length, and a UTF-8 encoding string.

On the client side, I get no errors, but on the server side, this:

```
error: [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

occurs. The error happens at different lines every time, sometimes when `recv()`ing the identification byte, sometimes when reading the string length, sometimes when reading the string itself, and sometimes it works perfectly fine, just as it is supposed to.

What is going on here? The server computer has a firewall exception. The client connects, sends three pieces of data in succession, then closes the socket. Am I doing this too fast?

Thanks.

Comment: Please post (i.e. copy, paste, format for SO) relevant code fragments from server and client code. Preferably code that someone else can run to try this out on their own. Also, describe any [attempts you have made to solve this problem](http://whathaveyoutried.com/) and why you think they did not work.

Comment: The code that manages this is dispersed over several classes, @crazeewulf, it would be a large effort trying to reconstruct that in a  reusable way. This error looks like a socket-level error and I was hoping that someone would give me a general answer with the general information I supplied. If that doesn't happen, I'll produce samples. Thanks.

Comment: OP, in that case, write your own tiny TCP server and client using [this](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socketserver.html#socketserver-tcpserver-example) code as an example and send the same data as your large application over and over. See if you can reproduce the problem. Report the results with this test code and error messages (if any). Basically, try to boil the problem down to a small code fragment that can be used by others on SO to debug this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this wasn't a long-lived question.

It looks like I was closing the socket client-side too fast, after adding a limit, I stopped getting the error.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The usual reason for this problem is writing to a connection that had already been closed by the peer: in other words an application protocol error, writing data that was never going to be read.